# I'm having trouble calling a method from one class to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call this method from my script enemy to my script player can anyone guide me?

The first namespace of code is enemy second is player

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
   DamageDealer damageDealer = other.gameObject.GetComponent<DamageDealer>();
   ProcessHit(damageDealer);
}

public void ProcessHit(DamageDealer damageDealer)
{
   health -= damageDealer.GetDamage();
   if (health <= 0)
   {
       Destroy(gameObject);
   }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific! there are three methods shown here, not one. also are they part of "Enemy" or some other class? if so, please provide the code for the Enemy class and the player class! please clarify your question a little more!

Comment: the first 2 methods are the enemy script the last method is the player script

Comment: so, OnTriggerEnter2D and ProcessHit should both be accessible by both classes, but OnTriggerEnter2D should work differently for the enemy and the player?

Comment: well i have to enter the code for the player type in the second OnTrigger but i dont know what to put there

Comment: I tried using        findObjectOfType<Enemy>();            Enemy.DamageDealer();     but its not working

Comment: it wont be Enemy.DamageDealer unless thats a public static part of Enemy.. What class is DamageDealer

Answer (score 1):

Try having an abstract base class that is common for both `Enemy` and `Player`- E.g `Character` or whatever makes sense for your program.

```
  public abstract class Character
    {

    public virtual void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        DamageDealer damageDealer = other.gameObject.GetComponent<DamageDealer>();
        ProcessHit(damageDealer);
    };

    public void ProcessHit(DamageDealer damageDealer)
    {
        //ProcessHit accessible for all classes that inherit Character
        health -= damageDealer.GetDamage();
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
public class Enemy : Character
{
    //this has both methods as declared in Character
}
public class Player : Character
{
    // this needs to be overriden for Player
    public override void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        //Enter OnTriggerEnter2D logic for Player
    }
}
```

So if you want any class that has OnTriggerEnter2D to act in a different way, just override it and change the logic.